# finding residue for complex analysis

Tags: residue-calculus

I am having a tough time finding the residue for a function, suppose my test function is

$$\frac{z^2}{{(z^2+a^2)}^2}$$

while I could determine the poles to be $+-ai$ and I know the formula to find the residue to be

$$a_{-1}= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int f(z) dz$$

but I am confused, if I have to integrate the aforementioned function now and divide it by $2\pi i$ to find the residue or what. nay hint or suggestion would be appreciated .

Comment: You need to integrate $f(z)$ along a contour surrounding one of the poles.

Comment: can you give me a little hint on how to do contour integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contour for calculating residue is a closed curve surrounding the pole you want to calculate. The contour integral is
$$ \oint_\gamma f(z)dz = \oint_a^b f(z(t)) z'(t) dt
$$
where $z$ is a parametrisation of the curve $\gamma$.

In your case, the parametrisation could be $e^{i t} \pm ai, t \in [0, 2\pi]$